# Extending Array to be friendly to custom logging

Tags: arrays, swift, logging, protocols

I have the following code where I define a `Loggable` protocol and I want any `Array` in my app where the `Element` type conforms to `Loggable` to be easily converted into a string.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

protocol Loggable {
    var logDescription: String { get }
}

struct Node: CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: Int

    var description: String {
        return "node: \(self.id) \n"
    }
}

let node1 = Node(id: 1)
let node2 = Node(id: 2)

let nodes = [node1, node2]

print(nodes)

extension Array: Loggable where Element: Loggable {

    var logDescription: String {
        var message = ""
        for element in self {
            message += element.logDescription
        }
        return message
    }
}


struct Logger {
    static func log(item: Loggable) {
        print(item.logDescription)
    }
}


Logger.log(item: nodes)
```

Unfortunately, I get `Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause`.  Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

More broadly, I'd appreciate any recommendations or links to using Swift functionality to achieve cleaner log messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right general idea, but a few errors in execution:

1. First you need to make `Node`, the element of your arrays, conform to the `Loggable` protocol. The array itself doesn't need to conform because it is just a container of `Loggable` objects

   ```
   struct Node: Loggable, CustomStringConvertible {
       let id: Int

       var description: String {
           return "node: \(self.id) \n"
       }

       var logDescription: String {
           return "logDescription"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Modify your `Logger`'s log function to be a generic function with a constraint that the parameter should conform to the `Loggable` protocol

   ```
   struct Logger {

       static func log<T>(item: T) where T: Loggable {
           print(item.logDescription)
       }

       static func log<T>(items: [T]) where T: Loggable {
           for item in items {
               print(item.logDescription)
           }
       }

       // Bonus functional points

       // static func log<T>(items: [T]) where T: Loggable {
       //     items.forEach() { print($0.logDescription) }
       // }

   }
   ```
3. Now you can call the log functions as expected

   ```
   let node1 = Node(id: 1)
   let node2 = Node(id: 2)
   let nodes = [node1, node2]

   Logger.log(items: nodes)
   ```

---

You should look at [CustomDebugStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customdebugstringconvertible) as it fulfills a very similar function from the standard library.

Comment: somewhat relatedly, is it possible to make a protocol conform to another protocol? e.g., you made `Node` conform to a protocol, but say `Node` was a protocol.  Say I wanted all `Node`'s to conform to `Hashable`, is that possible?

Comment: and what is the specific reason why `Logger.log` should take a generic with constraint of `Loggable` as opposed to just `Loggable`? in both cases doesn't the argument behave as a `Loggable`?